# JavaFX - OME while storing data in HSQLDB from JSON data

Tags: java, performance, javafx-2, hsqldb

I have used the HSQLDB for storing the data in my app. I make 15 Web service call one by one. and store the data in DB. It's working fine for medimum amount of data. I got the OME(Out of memory error) for large data. I mean, suppose I am having like 20k records for web service method.So we are getting the OME while storing the data into the DB. I tried with profiler feature also but I am unable to find which object was consumed more heap memory. So I struck here. I need the somebody help to solve this.

```
Code

 try {
            JSONObject jSONObject = getJSONData(clientId, ApplicationConstants.REST_METHOD_GET_ALL_CATEGORIES_LIST_BY_CLIENT_ID);
            if (jSONObject != null) {
                JSONArray jSONArray = jSONObject.getJSONArray(ApplicationConstants.JSON_OBJECT_RESPONSE);
                Integer length = jSONArray.length();
                if (length == 0) {
                    if (_logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                        _logger.info("Categories not found for client {}", clientId);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (_logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
                        _logger.info("{} Categories found for client {}", length, clientId);
                    }

                    SyncDao synDao = (SyncDao) getDAO(ApplicationConstants.REST_SYNC_DAO);

                    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                        JSONObject jSONObj = jSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ProjectMenu projectMenu = new ProjectMenu();
                        projectMenu.setClientId(clientId);
                        projectMenu.setCategory(ApplicationConstants.PROJECT_MENU_CATEGORY_SUB_MENU);
                        projectMenu.setCategoryType(ApplicationConstants.CATEGORY_TYPE_CATEGORY);
                        projectMenu.setCreatedDate(jSONObj.getString(ApplicationConstants.REST_CATEGORY_CREATED_DATE));
                        projectMenu.setElementId(jSONObj.getString(ApplicationConstants.REST_CATEGORY_ID));
                        projectMenu.setIsLeaf(Boolean.FALSE);
                        projectMenu.setLabel(jSONObj.getString(ApplicationConstants.REST_CATEGORY_NUMBER));
                        projectMenu.setLevel(new Integer(4));
                        projectMenu.setSortOrder(jSONObj.getInt(ApplicationConstants.REST_CATEGORY_SORT_ORDER));
                        // Getting parent menu details
                        ProjectMenu parentProjectMenu = synDao.getProjectMenu(clientId, 
                                jSONObj.getString(ApplicationConstants.REST_CATEGORY_PROJECT_COMPONENT_ID), ApplicationConstants.CATEGORY_TYPE_COMPONENT);
                        if (parentProjectMenu != null) {
                            if (ApplicationConstants.REST_NO_COMPONENT_LABEL.equalsIgnoreCase(parentProjectMenu.getLabel())) {
                                projectMenu.setParentMenuId(parentProjectMenu.getParentMenuId());
                            } else {
                                projectMenu.setParentMenuId(parentProjectMenu.getId());
                            }
                            projectMenu.setProjectId(parentProjectMenu.getProjectId());
                        }

                        if (_logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                            _logger.debug("Persisting Category: {}", projectMenu.toString());
                        }
                        synDao.persist(projectMenu);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException jsonex) {
            if (_logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
                _logger.error("Exception while synchronizing Categories.", jsonex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Wait.. are you fetching all records from table or what? I don't understand your question.

Comment: I am fetching the data from the database using web service method and then I am storing it in the HSQLDB.

Answer (score 0):

Use of MEMORY tables is often the cause for OOM errors when the amount of data in the database gets larger.

Convert the tables that hold large amounts of data to CACHED tables and there won't be any more OOM errors.

```
SET TABLE t TYPE CACHED
```